# Creating a 1-D array of strings from user input in C

Tags: arrays, c, segmentation-fault, scanf

I was attempting to create an array from user input in C. My code was as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char** create_array(int num);

int main(){
    char** my_array;
    int i;
    printf("%s", "Input the size of the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    my_array = create_array(i);
    for (int m = 0; m < i; m++){
        printf("%s\n", (char*)my_array[m]);
    }
}
char ** create_array(int num){
    char** array = malloc(num * sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        char temp[32];
        printf("Input element %d of the array: ", i);
        scanf("%s", temp);
        array[i] = temp;
    }
    for (int m = 0; m < num; m++){
        printf("%s\n", array[m]);
    }
    printf("end of func\n");
    return array;
}
```

I was having (possibly unrelated?) issues with segmentation faults until I replaced the declaration of `temp` from `char *temp;` to `char temp[32];`. I am not sure of why declaring `temp` as a char pointer creates the segmentation fault, if that is a simple related answer let me know, if not I will ask in another question.

However, when I run this code, upon inputting

```
Input the size of the array: 2
Input element 0 of the array: value0
Input element 1 of the array: value1
```

I get

```
value1
value1
end of func


Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

So to me it seems like temp somehow isn't changing when the for loop executes next iteration. I'm not sure why or how that would ever happen though. I also tried changing

`printf("%s\n", my_array[m]);`

to

`printf("%s\n", (char*)my_array[m]);`

but that didn't seem to help either.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you have the `num` parameter is you're going to immediately overwrite it with `scanf`?

Comment: @BradyDean you're right, that was leftovers from a previous attempt I forgot to remove. updated the question, thanks!

Comment: `char temp[32]` should only be used in the scope it's declared. Once the scope ends, accessing that memory results in Undefined Behavior. You should dynamically allocate memory for it instead: `char* temp = malloc(32)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for. The trick is allocate the memory for the strings on the heap. Saving pointers to `char temp[32];` is dangerous because it's in automatic storage. As @Spikatrix said in a comment, that memory is not guaranteed to be in a valid state between each iteration of the loop. With the data on the heap, there's a well-defined region of memory set aside and identified by the pointer returned from `malloc`.

There's also a lot of good reason to not use `scanf`. As is, your code does not do any bounds checks and can easily overwrite the 32-byte array allocated for each string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char** create_array(int num);

int main(){

    int num_strings;
    printf("Input the size of the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &num_strings);
    printf("\n");

    char** my_array = create_array(num_strings);

    for (int i = 0; i < num_strings; i++){
        printf("%s\n", my_array[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_strings; i++) {
        free(my_array[i]);
    }

    free(my_array);
}

char** create_array(int num) {

    char** array = malloc(num * sizeof(char*));

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        array[i] = malloc(32);
        printf("Input element %d of the array: ", i);
        scanf("%s", array[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("end of func\n");
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Yep, that did it! Is there a better way you would do it to avoid exceeding the memory limit without setting it just to like 1024?

Comment: @BenjaminFasick https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf/2430310

Comment: @BenjaminFasick http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html this is good too